# last date of Financial year (I.e 2017-03-31)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi please let me know how to extract the last day of Financial year in sql server.my financial year start from 2016-04-01 to 2017-03-31

Comment: so if you pass 2014, do you want `2014-03-31` or `2015-03-31` in output?

Comment: I have From_Date and To_Date parameter it will change dyanamically.If i pass from date parameter as 2017-04-01 then i want result should be 2018-03-31

Comment: Check my updated [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43235201/5234334)

Answer (score 1):

Closest you can use is End Of Month for that you need to provide one date to that month as below:

```
select eomonth('2017-03-01')
```

Comment: I am using sql server 2008R2

Answer (score 0):

To get the last day of the financial year for any date, you need to find the last of march if before march, or the last of march next year if after march:

```
declare @yourdate datetime = getdate();
select case when month(@yourdate) < 4 then CONVERT(datetime,cast(YEAR(@yourdate) as char(4)) + '-03-31'  ,120)
            else  CONVERT(datetime,cast(YEAR(@yourdate) + 1 as char(4)) + '-03-31'  ,120)
       end as financial_year_end
```

Comment: Thank you Kannan.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
If you want last date derived based on from_date, then use something like this

<kbd>**[`Rextester Demo`](http://rextester.com/WCMHA37990)**</kbd>

```
select 
    case when datepart(mm,from_date) <=3 then 
        cast(concat(year(from_date),'-03-31') as datetime) 
    else 
        dateadd(year,1,cast(concat(year(from_date),'-03-31') as datetime))
end as last_date_fin
from 
(select '2017-04-30' as from_date union all
select '2017-01-13') t;
```

This way `from_date` between `Jan` - `Mar` will give same year's `31st march`. Else it will give next year's `31st March`.

Previous answer:

http://rextester.com/AXVM26769

If you want to get last day of march for same year as passed, then use

```
select cast(concat(given_year,'-03-31') as datetime) 
from 
(select '2017' as given_year) t
```

If you want to pass 2016 and then get `2017-03-31` then use. You can change the year in derived table and change the output based on that.

```
select dateadd(year,1,cast(concat(given_year,'-03-31') as datetime)) 
from 
(select '2016' as given_year) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code will work to find the last date of Financial Year.
 For Previous Year case matches and 'THEN' part will Execute and for current year 'ELSE' 
 part will execute.

```
select CASE WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE())) <= 3 
THEN convert(varchar(4), YEAR(GETDATE())-1) + '-' + '03-31' 
ELSE convert(varchar(4),YEAR(GETDATE()))+ '-'  + '03-31'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> LastDayOfYearFY] = 
>     eomonth( dateadd(month, 5, 
>                      dateadd(year, datepart(year, (dateadd(month, 6, [date])) ) -1900, 0)))
```

Idea extension taken from [return-first-day-of-financial-year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961530/return-first-day-of-financial-yearapril-1st-t-sql)

Answer (score -1):

You can select all the dates order them descendant and take the first one.

```
SELECT date
FROM table
ORDER BY date desc
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: The question says sql server...your answer is for mysql.