# Return First day of Financial Year(April 1st) T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, getdate

First Day of financial year is April 1st.

T-SQL Query to return April 1st for the  `getdate()`

Financial Year: April 1st to March 31st

Comment: What are you actually looking for here?

Comment: You can define a UDF where you can return April 1st of current year. Anyhow first day of financial year never going to be changed.

Comment: Create a calendar table, it will solve more than 1 date/time problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select DATEFROMPARTS(Yr, 4, 1) [start], DATEFROMPARTS(Yr + 1, 3, 31) [end] from 
(select case when DATEPART(month, getdate()) < 4 then DATEPART(year, getdate()) - 1 else DATEPART(year, getdate()) end Yr) a
```

Answer (score 3):

```
declare @today  date = '2018-06-21'

select  fin_year = dateadd(month, 3, 
                           dateadd(year, 
                                   datepart(year, 
                                            dateadd(month, -3, @today)) - 1900, 0))
```

the expression `datepart(year, dateadd(month, -3, @today))` is to get the current financial year. Since your financial year is Apr 1, for Jan 1 to Mar 31, subtracting 3 months from it, will give you the correct year (fiscal year = financial year).

After that it is just to form the date Apr 1 with that year

Comment: And last day of FY could be   LastDayOfYearFY]      = eomonth(dateadd(month, 5, dateadd(year, datepart(year, (dateadd(month, 6, [date])) ) -1900, 0)))   thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @DateToUse DATETIME = GETDATE(),
        @FinancialYearStart DATETIME
DECLARE @DayPart INT = DATEPART(DAY, @DateToUse),
        @MonthPart INT = DATEPART(MONTH, @DateToUse),
        @YearPart INT = DATEPART(YEAR, @DateToUse),
        @StartMonth INT = 4, -- April
        @StartDay INT = 1 -- 1st

SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS((
        @YearPart - CASE 
            WHEN @MonthPart > @StartMonth
                OR (
                    @MonthPart = @StartMonth
                    AND @DayPart >= @StartDay
                    )
                THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END
        ), @StartMonth, @StartDay, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

I just knocked this up and it produces `2020-04-01 00:00:00.000` **right now**. I threw some other dates at it and it seemed to work nicely. Obviously the month/day can easily be changed by changing the variables at the top.

It's not the shortest block of SQL, but it's easy to use for different dates. A lot of other answers I've seen across different questions have returned different formats like a string or just the year part. Whereas this datetime will allow it to be used for datetime comparisons.